# How to position my text in the table (table has centered on the page)

Tags: html, css

I have a table, please check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fqjzX/4/) .

As you saw, there are two columns in a row, the first column shows the "Logo", the second columns shows the language selection. I have already used CSS to center the table on the page.

My questions are:

how to CSS to put the language texts 10px to the right border of the table, and vertically in the middle of the row?

Answer (score 2):

`text-align:right; padding-right:10px;` should do it.

Your tables appear to already be vertically aligned, but if not add `vertical-align:middle` to the table cells.

Answer (score 0):

> how to CSS to put the language texts 10px to the right border of the
>   table, vertically in the middle?

Give some padding to your #language div, like so:

```
#language {
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

> how to position the "logo" text in the middle of the cell both
>   horizontally and vertically?

To center your logo use this:

```
div h1 {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/fqjzX/7/